# RShiny: How to pass variable from Server.R to an RMD script

Tags: r, scope, knitr, shiny

I am playing around with RShiny recently, and I've built a working web interface that takes two parameters "date" and "location" and gives me back a series of graphs and tables from our database that fit the criteria.

What I would like to do with that, is to have users being able to download all the data and graphs in the form of a RMD report in HTML format.

so I have 
1. UI.R with a download button
2. Server.R's downloadHandler starts my RMD script
3. ????

UI.R

```
downloadButton('downloadData','Download')
```

Server.R

```
output$downloadData<- downloadHandler(filename ="myData.html", 
                                  content= function(file= NULL){
                                    knit(thread.RMD) 
                                  }
```

Comment: Could you paste Winston's answer here? http://groups.google.com/group/shiny-discuss/browse_thread/thread/5e65bd574d7812d2

Comment: thanks for the reminder. It has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the answer I got from the Shiny Google Group : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/shiny-discuss/XmW9V014EtI

The function that's given as the 'content' argument to downloadHandler takes one option, 'file'. When the download button is clicked, the download handler calls that function, and it uses the file argument to tell it where is should save the output file.

I don't see a way to set the output file name from knit2html(), but you can just rename it after it's created:

```
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename ="ShinyData.html", 
    content = function(file) {
      knit2html("myreport.rmd")
      file.rename("myreport.html", file)
    }
  )
```

(Also, you're missing a closing parenthesis in ui.r.)

-Winston